# Method has array param, passing array objects to parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I have a constructor that has a similar signature to `ExampleObject(string name, params object[])`.

My usual procedure of passing items to this constructor is:

```
var thisObject = new ExampleObject("name", obj1, obj2, obj3);
```

Is there anyway I can initialize a separate array of objects, and pass that array to the constructor IN Addition to how I normally do it, by means of LINQ or some other magic?

Ideal result:

```
object[] specialObjects = {new object("specObj1"), new object("specObject2")}
var thisObject = new ExampleObject("name", obj1, obj2, specialObjects...
```

Would I need to use LINQ's Enumerable, ForEach, or something I'm completely unaware of, or is something like this not feasible and I should include obj1 and obj2 into specialObjects?

Comment: @JeffMercado That is assuming the OP has control over the implementation of `ExampleObject`, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: I don't, but, good to know that's also an option in the future if I do have control over the implementation.

Comment: You don't necessarily need access to an class implementation to do what you need. You _always_ have the option to create methods to bundle operations you can't do directly. Create a method that matches your usage pattern and implement it using what's available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `params` keyword is just syntactic sugar for the creation of an array - you could as well do it with an array literal, i.e.

```
var thisObject = new ExampleObject("name", new [] {obj1, obj2, obj3});
```

Once you look at it this way, you realize that it is not possible to use an array for part of the parameter list. You have to create a new array. You could definitely use LINQ. Here is an example:

```
var thisObject = new ExampleObject("name", 
    (new [] {obj1, obj2}).Concat(specialObjects).ToArray());
```

(Note that there is a performance penalty involved in using code like this as several temporary objects are created. If you are concerned about performance it may be a better idea to create a specialized overload that takes the array and extra parameters).